# Is it physically possible the existence of moons or planets where objects float permanently above the surface?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, planets, moon, tidal-effect

I found the following exercise while studying gravitation:

> A small moon of mass $m$ and radius orbits a planet of mass M, keeping the same face towards the planet. Show that, if the moon approaches the planet closer than $ r_c=a(3M/m)^{1/3} $, loose rocks lying on the surface of the moon will be lifted off.

The concept made me wonder: Is it really possible that a planet or moon could have objects floating permanently above the surface because of the influence of close celestial bodies?

Comment: Look up Roche limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it cannot happen because of a natural instability in the gravitational forces.

Gravitational forces are inversely proportional to the distance between the objects squared.  If that distance decreases, then the forces will increase.

There will be a key balancing point where the forces of gravity are exactly equalized.  At this point the object is in "free fall" which I believe is what you describe with the floating bodies.  However, should it move any closer to the moon, the effects of the planet decrease and the effects of the moon increase.  This will cause the object to immediately tumble up to the moon (or, perhaps more technically correct: tumble down to the moon).  A slight nudge in the other direction, towards the planet, causes the planets gravity to have a larger effect -- the object tumbles to the planet.

An object in this free-fall state is called "metastable."  The forces are in balance, but any slight perturbation causes the balance to be disrupted.  To have floating objects over the surface of a planet, you need stability.  This could be caused by a string tying it to the planet when it's close enough to the moon to be drawn upward.  This is a key aspect of the construction of a hypothetical space elevator.

Comment: Apologies for the late answer to this. If the forces from the planet and the moon on the object are equal and cancel each other, keeping the object "suspended in the air/floating", is still considered that the object is on "free fall"?

Comment: @Jon Most everyone would consider it in free fall.  In every scientific community I am aware of (there's always dissenters), free-fall is a local property associated with everything in the local system being accelerated equally.  As a counter example, you are not currently in free fall because some of your atoms (on the bottom of your body) are being pushed on by the chair/floor and not others.  This definition of free-fall is the one Einstein used in his thought experiments for relativity, so it's by far the most popular.

Comment: This typical definition of free fall is that you cannot determine your acceleration locally, such as by using tension on springs.  You can only determine your acceleration by looking out globally at other objects (such as the planet below you).